# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' SELECT ' to data type int

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this query:

```
DECLARE @selectsql nvarchar(4000),
DECLARE @cnt int

select @selectsql = ' SELECT ' + @cnt + '= COUNT(*) FROM Vwbckup' 

print @selectsql
print @cnt

EXEC sp_executesql @selectsql
```

When I execute the query I'm getting this error:

> *Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' SELECT ' to data type int.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't apparently need dynamic SQL for this but in case you do for some reason not shown you don't need to concatenate that part at all. You can use an `OUTPUT` parameter.

```
DECLARE @selectsql NVARCHAR(4000),
        @cnt       INT

SELECT @selectsql = N'SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) FROM Vwbckup'

PRINT @selectsql

PRINT @cnt

EXEC sp_executesql
  @selectsql,
  N'@cnt int output',
  @cnt OUTPUT

SELECT @cnt
```

Answer (score 8):

Your @cnt variable is of type INT - you need to cast it to NVARCHAR to concatenate together:

```
DECLARE @selectsql nvarchar(4000),
DECLARE @cnt int

SELECT @selectsql = N' SELECT ' + CAST(@cnt AS NVARCHAR(10)) + N'= COUNT(*) FROM Vwbckup'
```

Plus: you should **prefix** your string literals with `N` to indicate Unicode (`NVARCHAR`) strings

**Update:** that previous command really doesn't make any sense at all.... did you mean to create this command string?

```
SELECT @selectsql = N' SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) FROM Vwbckup'
```

and then execute it?

Comment: Yes, but i wrote other queries also without using N and they are executing

Answer (score 0):

### Concatenating an `int` into a string => cast it

The problem is not when SQL is being executed but before it gets generated because you're concatenating strings and integer variable.

You should cast your integer variable:

```
select @selectsql = 'SELECT ' + cast(@cnt as nvarchar) + ' = COUNT(*) FROM Vwbckup'
```

But you do realise that variable's value is going to be concatenated into your resulting string. I'm not sure you want that...